# Insert values in Postgres based on select distinct

Tags: postgresql

I have the following table ,

```
XTable

id | mapname | category | value
1    mapone.   cat1.       val1
2.   mapone    cat2        val2
3.   mapone.   cat3.       val3
4.   maptwo.   cat1        val1
5.   maptwo.   cat2        val4
```

Now i need to do the followin

for every distinct mapname insert a row with the same mapname but a different category

So something like this ,

`insert into XTable values (DEFAULT,"my_new_category","valueone");`

The problem is I cannot come across a sql that does this looping thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a window function:

```
SELECT id,
       mapname,
       'cat' || row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY mapname ORDER BY id) AS category,
       value
FROM atable;
```

Comment: Thank you for your time.  I am unable to figure out how to figure the insert into this.Can you please point me towards a case where i can issue the insert statement .

Comment: You can simply use my query with `INSERT INTO ... SELECT ...`.